# Why does Console.WriteLine(3 + 'z' + 4); result in 129 in C#?

Tags: c#, parameters, char, concatenation, console.writeline

This is something they included as part of my course, just wondering why it does this and what they were trying to show with it but can't seem to figure it out. Is it some sort of principle when trying to concatenate chars to numbers? 
Am I right in assuming that 'z' is a char because it's in single quotes here?

Is it some sort of error because you shouldn't write stuff like this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Implicit conversion from char to int. I'm sure there's a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: The character code of 'z' is: 122. It converts to integers before addition.

Comment: This is a duplicate of `char + char = int? Why?`, which is itself a duplicate. I don't think we need another question on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

`z` is char value, char is basically a number. `z` will be implicitly converted to `int` (`z` code is `122`), that's why `3 + 'z' + 4 == 129`. It will be converted to `int` because in statement `3 + 'z'` `3` is `int`, so result of addition will be also `int`.

Answer (score 0):

In C# [char](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/char) is a 16 bit numeric value which represents a unicode [character](https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=122). So in your case `z` is implicitly evaluated as `122`. So `3 + 122 + 4` equals `129`.